# Density funtion for $Z := X + Y$, with $X$ and $Y$ being i.i.d. (exponential distribution)

Tags: integration, probability-theory

> Assume $X, Y$ are two random variables that are exponential distributed with parameter $\beta > 0$ and independet from each other. Define $Z := X + Y$. Determine the density function of $Z$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., we are allowed to use the fact that $X + Y$ possesses the density function $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(r-s)f(s) ds,$$

with $f(r-s)$ respectively $f(s)$ being the density function of $X$ and $Y$. For $s \ge 0$, the density function of an exponential distributed random variable is given by $f(s) = \beta e^{-\beta s}$, and since it is $0$ otherwise, we can rewrite the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(r-s)f(s) ds = \int_{0}^{\infty} \beta e^{-\beta (r-s)} \beta e^{-\beta s} ds =  \beta^2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r\beta} ds,$$

which disappears to $\infty$, unfortunately. What's my mistake here?

Comment: Take integral $\int_0^r\cdots ds$

Comment: Why should I be allowed to do that?

Comment: If $s>r$ then $f(r-s)=0$

Comment: Ah, of course! Didn't see that, thanks!